# Цвет div блока JS

Tags: javascript

```
d.onclick = function click21() {

      if(event.ctrlKey) { 
 d.style.background='#ccc';
} else { d.style.background='#6492cb';}


  }
```

Цвет при нажатии CTRL+click меняется на #ССС. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии CTRL+click цвет менялся на #CCC если нажмешь еще раз CTRL+click то с #CCC на #DDD и так к примеру 5 заготовленных заранее цветов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в код

```
var colors = [
    '#ccc',
    '#ddd',
    '#eee',
    '#fff',
    '#aaa'
];

var index = 0;

function getNextColor() {
    if (index >= colors.length) {
        index = 0;
    }

    return colors[index++];
}
```

и замените

```
d.style.background='#ccc';
```

на

```
d.style.background = getNextColor();
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89o2mqt1/)

Comment: срабатывает только на 1 цвет, а дальще цвета не меняются

Comment: @Павел добавил ссылку на jsFiddle в ответ, посмотрите, там пример с обычным кликом

Comment: спасибо большое, сработало)